# Counting nonzero hyperdeterminants over $\mathbb{F}_q$

Tags: co.combinatorics, finite-fields

The *hyperdeterminant*  $D(A)$ is a multidimensional generalization of the
determinant. It is a polynomial in the entries of a $(k_1+1)\times
(k_2+1)\times\cdots \times (k_n+1)$ array $A$. The hyperdeterminant is defined
when $2\max k_i\leq \sum k_i$. For further information see for
instance http://arxiv.org/pdf/1301.0472v1.pdf.

Assuming that $(k_1,\dots,k_n)$ satisfies the above condition, let
$N(q)$ be the number of nonzero $(k_1+1)\times\cdots\times(k_n+1)$
hyperdeterminants over the finite field $\mathbb{F}_q$. For instance,
if $n=2$ then $k_1=k_2$, and the number of $m\times m$ matrices over
$\mathbb{F}_q$ with nonzero determinant is well-known and easily seen
to equal $(q^m-1)(q^m-q)\cdots (q^m-q^{m-1})$. A few years ago some
M.I.T. graduate students computed that for $2\times 2\times 2$
hyperdeterminants we get a polynomial in $q$, though I seem to have
misplaced the formula. Can anything be said about the general case? Do
we always get a polynomial in $q$? (This seems unlikely to me.) Can
someone compute the $2\times 2\times 3$ case?

Comment: Is there a good introduction to hyperdeterminants for non-algebraic geometers (or, rather, algebraic non-geometers)? All definitions I've seen are horrendously implicit.

Comment: Are you asking (for a fixed tuple) the count of the domain of D(A) ( when restricted to those A for which D(A) is not zero), or the count of the range (which I imagine is always a polynomial in q), or the count of something else? (To me it seems you are conflating hyperdeterminants with the matrices from which they are derived.)  Your example for n=2 seems to reference the domain, but it is not clear.  Gerhard "Is Often Confused By Words" Paseman, 2016.03.04.

Answer (score 3):

I saw this question years ago and thought it was interesting. I never got around to doing anything with the question, but today I happened to come across some slides of Steven Sam with some data on the problem. I imagine the slides refer to the same M.I.T. students alluded to in the question. The slides can be found on Steven Sam's [website](http://math.ucsd.edu/~ssam/talks/2011/finitefield.pdf) and information on hyperdeterminants is on pages 16, 17, and 18.

The count for $2 \times 2 \times 2$ is reported to be $(q^4 - 1)(q^4 - q^3)$ and is attributed to Musiker--Yu. Attributed to Lewis--Sam are counts for $2 \times 2 \times 3$, $2 \times 3 \times 3$, and $2 \times 2 \times 4$ which are
$$q^4(q-1)^4 [2]^2 [3]\\ q^{10}(q-1)^3[2]^2[3] \\ q^4(q-1)^2[3][4](q^3+q^2-1).$$

It says "Caveat: these need to be double-checked..." which I have not done. But now maybe I (or someone else) will be inclined to check since we have an expression to compare to.